# Why doesn't function parameter become key value when passed in as such?

Tags: javascript, parameters

In the following test function I pass in 2 values and return a simple object.  For some reason 'cat' isn't used as the key value and instead the placeholder x is used.  I'm sure there is an obvious explanation for this behavior but I can't see what it is.  Maybe my brain is just too sleepy.  Thanks for any help!

```js
"use strict";

let functionTest = function(x, y) {
   return console.log({x: y});
} 

functionTest('cat', 153);
```

I tried an arrow function and the result was the same.

```js
"use strict";

let functionTest = (x, y) => console.log({x: y});

functionTest('cat', 153);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the value with `[]`

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets [], that will be computed and used as the property name.
>   This is reminiscent of the bracket notation of the property accessor
>   syntax, which you might have used to read and set properties already.
>   Now you can use a similar syntax in object literals, too:

```js
"use strict";

let functionTest = function(x, y) {
   return console.log({[x]: y});
} 

functionTest('cat', 153);
```

Doc: [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: That definitely solved it.  But why do I need brackets for that?

Comment: If you don't put [], browser will treat x is key.

Comment: @DR01D, without the `[]` js will interpret it as `x` and not as a variable

Answer (score 2):

use `[X]`,this is ES6 grammar

```js
"use strict";

let functionTest = function(x, y) {
   return console.log({[x]: y});
} 

functionTest('cat', 153);
```